# How to make ionic v4 alertbox message should route to other pages

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, angular-routing, ionic4

I have a ion-alert component with a message of "To Myself" and "To Someone" . Those two should act like buttons and route to different page in the application. But (click) and [routerLink] or calling a route.navigate on the message attribute doesn't work. Any Suggestions?

It is basically taking it as a string and doesn't response to (click) events. i have tried giving route.navigate also, no luck.

```
async transferMoneyTo() {
        const alert = await this.alertController.create({
            header: "Send Money",

            message: `<p (click)="console.log("Clicked") class="dib" style="text-decoration:none;color:#333333; margin:1em;font-size: 1.1em;">To Myself</p>               
                  <p (click)="console.log("test"); toSomeone()" style="text-decoration:none;color:#333333;font-size: 1.1em;">To Someone</p>`,

            buttons: [
                {
                        text: "Cancel",
                    role: "cancel",

                },
                {
                    text: "OK",
                },
            ],

            cssClass: "alertbox-custom",
        });

        await alert.present();
    }
```

As soon as i hit the text "To Someone" it should perform an action.

Answer (score 2):

It's recommended to use handlers in the built-in button property of ion-alert. It should look something like this:

```
async presentAlertConfirm() {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      header: 'Send Money',
      message: 'Where would you like to send your money?',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          cssClass: 'secondary',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('User cancelled');
          }
        }, {
          text: 'To Myself',
          handler: () => {
            toMyself();
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'To Someone',
          handler: () => {
            toSomeone();
          }
        }
      ]
    });

    await alert.present();
  }
```

If this does not fit your needs then you should build your own custom modal to handle this - per the docs:

> If you require a complex form UI which doesn't fit within the
>   guidelines of an alert then we recommend building the form within a
>   modal instead.

[View the documentation here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/alert)

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I want to make the "message" attribute clickable. Is that a possibility? For example, i want "Where would you like to send the money?" as clickable so that i can route it.

Comment: You can try to use `onclick=""` instead of `(click)=""` in your message property, but I think you're probably going to have odd behavior going that route. I would still recommend creating a custom modal instead for something like this. Using a modal would allow you to pass data back and forth from the initial view as well. Good luck friend!